# WinForms show variable name from the [Design].cs

Tags: c#, winforms

I have got many forms in my `WinForms` app and i wanted to know if there is a fast way to identify the form name from the `[Design].cs` file.

For instance if you double click a `button` from the design `GUI` it will lead you to the `onClick` and you can see the variable name.

I wanted to know if there is a similar was for `TextBoxs`, `RadioButtons` etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the form, press F4 and you can see the form name in the properties panel.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select the form and press F4.It will show you the property of the form and Name also.